# How to retain sentences, line spaces, and paragraphs in text file

Tags: java, string, paragraph, sentence

I have to create a method that can take words from differently formatted text files, and then output them as they were after manipulation.

The manipulation is turning each word into Piglatin.

For example:
Input (read from textfile): I have a little frog,
Output (by printwriter): Iway avehay away ittlelay ogfray,

I already can turn the words themselves in PigLatin, but how do a put the file back as it was found (with orginial sentences and spacing)?

```
while(infile.hasNext()){
         String str2 = infile.next();
         String[] arr = str2.split(" ");
         String[] newArr = new String[arr.length];
         for(int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++){
            newArr[k] = pig(arr[k]);
         }
         for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
            outfile.println(" " + newArr[i] + " ");
         }
      }
      outfile.close();
      infile.close();
   }
```

All I have, which simply puts the words on each line. pig(String s) turns the words into pig latin.outfile write to the output file, and infile reads from the originial text files, as seen below.

The texts files are as follows:

```
pig
latin

this 
strange
```

```
I have a little frog,
His name is Jim.

I love him very much, 
And when he sees me
He knows it!
```

```
We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal.

That they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights.

Altering fundamentally the Forms of our Governments:

For suspending our own Legislatures.
```

Comment: use `print` instead of `println`

Comment: So you basically want to be able to extract out the words and change them without changing the non-word characters? I think you'll be able to find information elsewhere on extracting words out of text without just splitting on spaces. If you want the original non-word characters to be in the outfile you'll need to put them there.

Comment: @Ryan1729 Is there a way to do that systematically, like an algorithm?

Comment: You use scanner and replace function.

Comment: @OptimalOG One way is to go character by character and keep the word characters in a `StringBuffer` and whenever you go from a word character to a non-word character get the string out and call your `pig` method and put that string in the file. As you go, put every non-word character in the file.